# getting this error pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50])
print(s.loc[True,False,False,True,True])
```

Getting this error:
:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Procx flask>C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Procx flask/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Procx flask\test.py", line 5, in 
print(s.loc[True,False,False,True,True])
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 925, in **getitem**
return self._getitem_tuple(key)
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1103, in _getitem_tuple
self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 751, in _has_valid_tuple
self._validate_key_length(key)
File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 792, in _validate_key_length
raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: you are indexing with more than what you could. try this, and solve these by tracking your error. `print(s.loc[[True, False, False, True, True]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need filter by boolean by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) need boolean list or array pass:

```
s = pd.Series([10,20,30,40,50])
print(s[[True,False,False,True,True]])
0    10
3    40
4    50
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print(s.loc[[True,False,False,True,True]])
0    10
3    40
4    50
dtype: int64
```